# How does using array.map() in a useSelector() cause a component to re-render when an action is dispatched?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning about Redux right now and going through the tutorial information. They have a note in the [Reading State from the Store with useSelector](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#reading-state-from-the-store-with-useselector) section that says:

> useSelector compares its results using strict === reference
> comparisons,  so the component will re-render any time the selector
> result is a new reference!  This means that if you create a new
> reference in your selector and return it,  your component could
> re-render every time an action has been dispatched,  even if the data
> really isn't different.

It continues on to give this function as a bad example of what you might pass to your `useSelector()`

```
// Bad: always returning a new reference
const selectTodoDescriptions = state => {
  // This creates a new array reference!
  return state.todos.map(todo => todo.text)
}
```

Later on in the [Selecting Data in List Items by ID](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#selecting-data-in-list-items-by-id) section, they use this as an example as part of their explanation on the topic:

```
const selectTodoIds = state => state.todos.map(todo => todo.id)
const todoIds = useSelector(selectTodoIds)
```

How is this different from the first example of "bad" code? What would be the proper way to write this? Is the warning advising you not to use any arrays in the `useSelector()` hook? I don't really understand what it is meaning when it says an action could be dispatched that doesn't change the data but somehow affects the selector.

**Edit:**
As someone pointed out in the comments, if you keep reading it explains why they did what they did/how to not do such a thing, however, could someone please explain the last tiny question/statement I wrote? **What does it mean exactly when it says an action could be dispatched that doesn't change the data but still changes the reference, causing re-renders?** I get that the `map()` function can return a new array with the same data within it thus being a new reference, but I can't think of a situation in which an action would be dispatched that doesn't change any of that data but still somehow touches that selector's state. If the action doesn't affect the selector's specific state, then why would it re-render at all? I need a different example than the one in the tutorial because it's not doing it for me.

Comment: Keep reading - a bit later on the docs say "We said earlier that returning new array references in selectors causes components to re-render every time, and right now we're returning a new IDs array in `<TodoList>`. In this case, the contents of the IDs array should be the same if we're toggling a todo, because we're still showing the same todo items - we haven't added or deleted any. But, the array containing those IDs is a new reference, so `<TodoList>` will re-render when it really doesn't need to."  Then it goes on to explain alternatives that will avoid that problem.

Comment: `that selector's state.` is your misconception. Every selector runs when *any* data changes, there is only "state", not "a selectors state". The point of running a selector is partially to figure out if something changed, it's impossible to know before the selector runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your question 1:

> How is this different from the first example of "bad" code?

As you said already: It's not different. It's still bad code. Further down they explain how to handle that, e.g. comparing each array item individually (`shallowEqual`).

#### Your question 2:

> What does it mean exactly when it says an action could be dispatched that doesn't change the data but still changes the reference, causing re-renders?

You are probably referring to this sentence:

> ... your component could re-render every time an action has been dispatched ...

You misunderstood that sencence:

The sentence doesn't say that dispatching the action changes the reference.

What they wanted to say is that dispatching an action would *indirectly* make the selector run again. I.e. changing something makes React re-render, a re-render makes the selector run again, and that action changes something. If dispatching the action wouldn't cause any changes (e.g. the reducer would find that nothing needs to be updated), then the selector wouldn't be called again.

The new reference is then created inside the selector, by the `.map()` function.

So the dispatched action doesn't change anything, but *after* you query the state, you would create a new array. E.g.:

```
const arrayState = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const selectedArrayWithMap = arrayState.map( item => item );
const selectedArrayNoMap = arrayState;

console.log( selectedArrayWithMap === arrayState ); // <-- false
console.log( selectedArrayNoMap === arrayState );   // <-- true
```